# Nonexistence of Pythagorean triple with largest side prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

**The Problem:** In the Pythagorean triplets **(a,b,c)** when **a < b** then **b** can't be a prime number.

**The Background**: While searching the properties of Pythagorean triplets in web I saw quite a few listed, but didn't see the above one which I thought was true, because I had developed a proof.

**The Request:** As discussed many a times in this site I would request some alternate proofs (or counterexamples) before I share mine for a review.

Comment: $ 5^2 + 12^2 = 13^2  $

Comment: @Will, $12$ isn't prime, right? Or did Grothendieck say otherwise?

Comment: @J.M., good point, I misread. Let me think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ a^2\! + p^2 = c^2\:\Rightarrow\: p^2 = (c\!-\!a)(c\!+\!a).\:$ Unique factorization $\:\Rightarrow \begin{eqnarray}\rm\:c\!-\!a &=&1\\ \rm c\!+\!a &=&\rm p^2\end{eqnarray}\:$ contra $\rm\,a<p$

Comment: My answer was something along your line -only the end logic was different. Since we know that $a<b<c=a+1$ It shows that $a<b<a+1$ implying $b$,an integer, should lie between two consecutive integers which is a fallacy.

Comment: @Barun Yes, that's the the proof I hinted at (I wanted to leave something for the reader).

Answer (score 7):

We use ["Euclid's" formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) for generating the Pythagorean triples. The job can be done much more elegantly, with much less machinery. Please see Bill Dubuque's answer.

The Pythagorean triples all have shape $k(x^2-y^2)$, $k(2xy)$, $k(x^2+y^2)$. 
Here $x$ and $y$ are positive integers such that $x \gt y$ (and $x$ and $y$ are  relatively prime, and of opposite parity, though these side facts do not matter for the proof). If a leg is to be prime we need $k=1$.

Certainly $2xy$ cannot be prime. And $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ cannot be prime unless $x=y+1$. So from now on we may assume that $x=y+1$.

So $x^2-y^2=(y+1)^2-y^2=2y+1$.  But $2xy=2(y-1)(y)=2y^2-2$.  We cannot have $2y+1\gt 2y^2-2$. So the leg $2y+1$ must be the smallest. In particular, the larger of the two legs cannot be prime.

Comment: Thanks Andre for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We begin with Euclid's formula shown here as
$$ A=m^2-k^2\qquad B=2mk \qquad C=m^2+k^2$$
At a glance, we can see that B is even and, in fact, B is always a multiple of $4.\quad$
To prove this, we substitute
$\quad m=(2n-1+k)\quad$ and get a formula I developed in $2009$ to generate only the subset of triples where $GCD(A,B,C)$ is an odd square which includes all primitives.
$$A=(2n-1+k)^2-k^2\quad B=2(2n-1+k)k \\
 C=((2n-1+k)^2+k^2)$$
becomes

\begin{align*}
  A=(2n-1)^2+          & 2(2n-1)k      \\ 
  B=  \qquad\quad\quad & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\ 
  C=(2n-1)^2+          & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\
\end{align*}

where B is the sum of two even numbers and thus a multiple of $4.\quad$ The formula generates

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89  \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169  \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 \\ \hline
Set_{6} &43,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281  \\ \hline
\end{array}]

By inspection, we can see that $B=4x, x\in\mathbb{N}$ includes all primitives and not just some double or quadruple of primitives. We can also see that half of all triples have $A>B$ and, no matter what, B is still a multiple of $4$. The conclusion is that B can never be prime.

Answer (score 0):

If $k,x,y\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $A=k(x^2-y^2), B=2kxy, C=k(x^2+y^2)$  and $A$ is prime, then, since $A=k(x-y)(x+y)$ is prime with $x+y>1$, we must have  $x-y=1.$ So $$\frac B A=\frac {2xy}{x^2-y^2}=\frac {2(y+1)y}{(y+1)^2-y^2}=$$ $$=\frac {2y^2+2y}{2y+1}>\frac {2y^2+y}{2y+1}=y\ge 1.$$